# Coupled nonlinear PDE, how to find solution, is this a well-known problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

During my weekly meeting with a student we stumbled upon a curious system of PDEs. Here $u,v$ are functions of $x,y$ and
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u^2+v^2 \qquad \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2uv$$
Furthermore, we know $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. I'm curious, are these PDEs a known problem (do they happen to have a name more specific than my title) and is it possible to solve these by some standard method. I found something already, but I don't want to bias the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this has a name, but the equations
$$ u_x=v_y=u^2+v^2,\qquad v_x=u_y=2uv$$
can be equivalently rewritten as
\begin{align}
(u+v)_x=(u+v)_y=(u+v)^2,\\
(u-v)_x=-(u-v)_y=(u-v)^2.
\end{align}
This has the obvious solution
$$-\frac{1}{u+v}=x+y+C_1,\qquad -\frac{1}{u-v}=x-y+C_2,$$
which may also be written as
$$u=-\frac{x+\alpha}{(x+\alpha)^2-(y+\beta)^2},\qquad v=\frac{y+\beta}{(x+\alpha)^2-(y+\beta)^2},$$
with $2\alpha=C_1+C_2$, $2\beta=C_1-C_2$.

Comment: Very nice. I found half of this already, I suppose now I just need to solve for $u$ and $v$. I wonder, will it work out to $$ u(x,y) = \frac{-(x+a)}{(x-a)^2-(y-b)^2} \qquad  v(x,y)=\frac{y+b}{(x-a)^2-(y-b)^2} $$ if it did then it justifies my other method for solving this pde... oh, the $a,b$ are constants.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Of course: $2a=-C_1-C_2$, $2b=-C_1+C_2$ (provided you correct your numerators).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to get some pen and paper to see it properly. Incidentally, I found your website link amusing.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I've updated my post to include the form closer to your answer.

Comment: Perfect! I made a typo in the comment, the constants should appear symmetrically in the numerator and denominator. Neat.

Comment: I just posted the manner in which I solved this problem at http://mathoverflow.net/q/143924/24854.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(u+v) = (u+v)^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(u-v) = (u-v)^2.
$$
Let $\nu = u+v$ and $\mu = u-v$, then are these just separable ODEs in $x$? We ignore the $y$ dependence for now, and find
$$
\nu = \frac{1}{f(y)-x},
$$
$$
\mu = \frac{1}{g(y)-x},
$$
perhaps solve for $u$ and $v$ and use the other conditions to find the arbitrary functions?

Comment: Thanks for the calculation, again, I wonder if this reduces to the solution I posted in the comment of O.L's answer...

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it does, sorry I didn't see your answer before I posted mine, you beat me to it!